# tcl: info frame gives mismatching line number with info body

Tags: tcl

See the following example:

```
$tclsh
% proc test {} {
    puts "line 2: [info frame 0]"
    # line 3 \ 
    line 4
    puts "line 5: [info frame 0]"
}
% test
line 2: type proc line 2 cmd {info frame 0} proc ::test level 0
line 5: type proc line 5 cmd {info frame 0} proc ::test level 0
% info body test

puts "line 2: [info frame 0]"
# line 3 line 4
puts "line 5: [info frame 0]"
```

The second `info frame` gives line 5 which is reasonable.
But it is in line 4 of the string returned by `info body` (because `\` is removed and line 3 and line 4 are joined together.)
Is it possible make the line numbers consistent between `info frame` and `info body`?

Comment: Oh, you've found `info frame`! It's rather strange (and very painful from a how-do-I-implement-a-Tcl-system perspective; tracking line numbers with that level of accuracy is surprisingly difficult).

Answer (score 0):

The `info frame` command is decidedly weird; it tries to return the line number from the place in which the code originated. If you put your code in a file, the `line` field will be the line number *in that file* (which will be named in the `file` field, which is present when code is `source`d). Here's a sample cut-n-paste from a terminal session that shows the real value:

```
bash$ cat test_frame.tcl 
package require Tcl 8.5
proc test {} {
    puts "line 2: [info frame 0]"
    # line 3 \
    line 4
    puts "line 5: [info frame 0]"
}
test
bash$ tclsh test_frame.tcl
line 2: type source line 3 file /home/dkf/test_frame.tcl cmd {info frame 0} proc ::test level 0
line 5: type source line 6 file /home/dkf/test_frame.tcl cmd {info frame 0} proc ::test level 0
```

Now I know this is irritating that you can't sync the line numbers up with the `info body` results, but getting the file line number is (well, probably) even more useful.

(Still, I wish we used this info in `errorInfo` trace messages; we go to a lot of work to build it and then hardly do anything with it…)

Comment: I was trying to develop a tiny debug tool with trace/info body/info frame. I need to know which line the script is running into (and stop there until user types 'contiue' or 'step'). And user may not use source command to run his script, so info frame may return with 'proc' type instead of 'source'.